# Trigger the form submit button from $().html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such a template when the user clicks the edit glyphicon, it will prompt a form for further editing:

```
<div class="post-menu pull-left">
    <a class="editCommentLink" href="#">
        <span id="{{ comment.id }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true">edit </span>
    </a> &nbsp
    <a class="delCommentLink" id="{{ comment.id }}" href="#">
        <span id="{{ comment.id }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">delete</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I employed ajax to send the get request and update the content with `$commentNew.html(commentEditForm)`;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){$(".editCommentLink").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var comment_id= $(e.target).attr("id")
    // Retrieve the top node of comment-right
    var $commentRight= $(e.target).closest(".comment-right")

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: `/ article/comment/edit /${comment_id}`,
        success: function(data){
            var ret=JSON.parse(data)
            var body=ret['body']

            var commentEditForm= `
            <form action="#" method="post" > {% csrf_token % }
            < div class="form-group" >
            < textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="editComment${comment_id}" >${body} < /textarea >
                        < button class="btn btn-primary" id="editSubmitBtn" > Save Edits < /button >
                        <a href="#" > cancel < /a >
            < / div >
            < /form >
            `
            var $commentNew= $commentRight.find(".post-text");
            $commentNew.html(commentEditForm);
        }, // success
    });//end of ajax
})//end edit click
</script>
```

However, there's no feedbacks when I am triggering button `id="editCommentBtn"` to submit the form data,

```
   });//end of ajax
})//end edit click

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    //still in edit click event    
    $("#editCommentBtn").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('button clicked');
       ...
    });//submit click event
})
```

I experiment to solve the problem, what confused me is that if I change `$(".editCommentBtn")` to its grandparent `$(".post-text")`, the browser alert me ('button clicked'),

I attempted to break the bulk of `var commentEditForm=` to single elements  like:

```
$newForm = $('<form action="#" method="post" > {% csrf_token % } < /form >');
$newFormGroup = $('< div class="form - group" >< / div >');
$newText = $('< textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="editComment${comment_id}" >${body} < /textarea >');
$newSubmit = $('< button class="btn btn-primary" id="editCommentBtn" > Save Edits < /button >')
$(.post-text).append($newForm);
$newForm.append($newFormGroup);
$newFormGroup.append($newText);
$newText.after($newSubmit);
```

There are many manual labors,
How to solve the problem elegantly?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to attach a click event to `.editCommentBtn` when the document loads, but they don't exist yet. This is one of the most common questions on StackOverflow, and is well documented here: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see element with Id `#editCommentBtn` in your unrendered code. But test this:

```
$(document).on("click","#editCommentBtn",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('button clicked');
});
```

With this way all elements that you inject them to your document (and have this id), will respond to this click function.